# SQL: Find date match outside or within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a Microsoft SQL Server, we have this table which logs property changes of users:

```
ID | userID | prop | changeDate
-------------------------------
 4   23      B       2017-02-18
 1   14      D       2013-05-19
 2   15      C       2014-04-10
 3   23      A       2016-01-11
```

What I would like to do is to query this table and find the active property within a range of dates.

For instance the period of `2016-08-01` to `2017-01-01` I would like to get `userID 23` with prop `A` because that was the active property for that user until it was changed on `2017-02-18`

I started out with the `changeDate BETWEEN '2016-08-01' and '2017-01-01'` but that only covers those cases where I have the exact start date.

I'm turning slightly insane. Is this quest even possible with this data? Or maybe I am asking the wrong question?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question.  What do you want returned if the user has multiple properties during the period.

Comment: That's a good point, Gordon. I simplified that part away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self join can help here.

```
CREATE TABLE x (ID INT, userID INT, prop CHAR(1), changeDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO x
  VALUES ( 4, 23, 'B', '20170218' ),
         ( 1, 14, 'D', '20130519' ),
         ( 2, 15, 'C', '20140410' ),
         ( 3, 23, 'A', '20160111' )

; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  x1.userID, x1.prop, x1.changeDate AS StartDate, MIN(x2.changeDate) AS ExitDate
  FROM    x x1
          LEFT OUTER JOIN x  x2
                  ON x1.changeDate < x2.changeDate
  GROUP BY x1.userID, x1.prop, x1.changeDate
)

SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   Startdate > = '20160801' 
  AND   ( ExitDate IS NULL OR ExitDate < '20170101' )
```

This gives you what you are looking for

```
userID | prop | StartDate               | ExitDate
--------------------------------------------------
 23       B      2017-02-18 00:00:00.000   NULL
```

Comment: Excellent. This is perfect! Thank you so much! I would group by changeDate, userID, prop. But other than that this really made my evening :)

Answer (score 2):

For a table of this type, the typical question is "What was a given users property as-of a particular date?"

This answers that question:

```
select pc.*
from (select pc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userId order by changeDate desc) as seqnum
      from propertychanges pc
      where changeDate <= @AsOfDate
     ) pc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting both a question and answer ;) I was quite lost there for a while. However the date-range is key in this case. So the typical question doesn't quite fit.